# How do I deploy a war file onto tomcat 6 using eclipse Juno

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse, html, tomcat

I am not familiar with build processes on Eclipse with javascript (HTML5) and Java resources.  But recently I got a war file from someone who asked me put it on tomcat (since the server where I used to access the project from is down).  I tried putting it under C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps... and then I restarted the tomcat which I have mounted on eclipse... and then I thought I will be able to access the project using localhost

```
http://localhost:8080/<warprojectfilename>
```

But I get 404...

Could someone let me know how could I deploy it on tomcat and access it using localhost like a website.

Thanks

Comment: Can you access `http://localhost:8080/`? It should display you Tomcat server page.

Comment: No I get the same error.  But I can access my other running websites on tomcat (I have them on eclipse) e.g. http://localhost:8080/someproject

Comment: @Tintin it looks like you ar running some other server using port 8080 try stop it (localhost:8080/someproject should not be accessible when server is stopped)

Comment: How do you start Tomcat from Eclipse? Do you use a Tomcat plugin or have you created a "Server"? If you have the Sysdeo Tomcat plugin you should see the configuration under Window -> Preferences -> Tomcat. If you created  a "Server" you should see the configuration under  Window -> Preferences -> Server -> Runtime Configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it was all static resource (javascript files)... I decided to extract the whole thing in a static web project on eclipse and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

it looks like you have got some other Tomcat (or other server using port 8080)running on your machine... please check which tomcat instance is running and stop it, or stop any other server running service that you mentioned is working fine...

You can stop tomcat server by going in to tomcat/bin 
and execute

```
 sh shutdown.sh
```

or

```
shutdown.bat
```

in windows

and to deploy war file to Tomcat server :

1) go to your Tomcat path

2) open webapps directory

3) paste your war file here

4) restart tomcat

5) now you should be able to access your app

Comment: Thanks for the reply but since it was all static resource (javascript files)... I decided to extract the whole thing in a static web project on eclipse and it worked. But I gave your answer an up for the useful information you gave...

Answer (score 2):

File -> import ->Web-War file this will import your .war as a web project.
goto Servers->tomcat->web modules-> add the imported web project. restart tomcat. you should be good